# What is the difference between using eq or not using it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, indexing, parent-child

Correct me if i am right please:

*1- we use `$("p").parent().siblings().eq(0).text` *to select* `2`.

*2- we can do this also by  `$("p").parent().siblings().text()`  *to select* `2`.

Now my question is how  *1 and *2 is different, how `eq(0)` helps us to be more specific in this problem?

```
<div><p>1</p></div>
<div>2</div>
<script>
alert($("p").parent().siblings().eq(0).text());
</script>
```

Comment: Why would you think it wouldn't be 2?

Comment: Please, paste code here, not images with code

Comment: The key is to research what `.siblings()` does.

Comment: What is the output? Well when you run it it tells you.....

Comment: `console.log($("p"))); console.log($("p").parent());
console.log($("p").parent().siblings());
console.log($("p").parent().siblings().eq(0));
console.log($("p").parent().siblings().eq(0).text());`

Comment: Less steps would be `$("p").parent().next().text()`

Comment: I do ```console.log($("p").parent().siblings().html());```

and gives me **2** also, why we need eq(0)?

Comment: @charlietfl The point of an assignment like this is not to accomplish the specific task, it's to find out if the student understands what all the methods do.

Answer (score 3):

Follow it step by step:

`$("p")` selects the `<p>1</p>` element.

Its parent is the first `<div>` element.

That element's siblings are `<div>2</div>` and the `<script>` block.

`.eq(0)` means to select the first of those siblings (since indexing is zero-based), which is `<div>2</div>`.

`.text()` returns the text content of that DIV, which is `2`.

Comment: I do ```console.log($("p").parent().siblings().html());```

and gives me **2** also, why we need eq(0)?

Comment: It's not needed in this case because accessor functions default to the first element. But modification functions with operate on all the matching elements, so you need to use `.eq()` if you want to be more specific.